# Proof that equation has a unique solution

Tags: proof-writing, roots

Let $\phi(z)$ be the p.d.f. of a standard normal variable, $\Phi(z)$ the c.d.f. of a standard normal variable, and $z \in R$. For simplicity I will use the notation $\Phi=\Phi(z)$ and $\phi=\phi(z)$.

I want to show that the unique solution of the equation

$f(z)=-z\phi\Phi+z\phi^2(4 \Phi-3)+\phi^2(4\Phi -2)+\Phi(2\Phi^2-3\Phi+1)=0$

is $z=0$.

When $z=0 \rightarrow$ $\Phi=\frac{1}{2}$ and  we have that:
$f(0)=0+0+\phi^2(4\frac{1}{2}-2)+\frac{1}{2}(2\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}+1)=0$.

When I plot the function it looks like this:

[image]

Also in the limits $\infty$ and $-\infty$ the function $f()$ approaches $0$.

How do I prove that this value $z=0$ is the unique solution?

Thank you

Comment: You might be able to show that $f(x)=0$ implies $f'(x)<0$, as seems to be the case with $x=0$.

Comment: You could try showing that outside of $(-1, 1)$, we have $f'(z) >0$. Together with the limit at infinity being $0$ in either direction, means that the graph cannot cross the $z$-axis. I haven't done the calculations, and it looks like a mess, but that's the first thing I would try.

Comment: Directions for a half solution: by looking at the sign of the four terms of your equation, you can see that only the third one is negative for $z<0$. But for $z<0$, this term is smaller in absolute value than the fourth term. So the sum is always positive for $z<0$, which means that $f(z)$ has no zero for $z<0$.